# Fizzbuzz in C lang

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

This is the first time I have recoded in C for several years and I would like to know how clean my code is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0

void fizzbuzz(int n) {
    char result[9] = "";  // strlen("fizzbuzz") + 1 == 9
    if (n % 3 == 0) strcat(result, "fizz");
    if (n % 5 == 0) strcat(result, "buzz");
    if (!*result) sprintf(result, "%d", n);
    printf("%s\n", result);
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) fizzbuzz(i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I know that I could include `stdlib` so as not to have to define `EXIT_SUCCESS` myself, but as I only needed this constant, it's a little clearer and more efficient to do this I think.

Comment: C/C++ are particularly unforgiving languages. It's your responsibility to abide by the rules or face the consequences. This is why, even in trivial cases, I would rather not deliberately violate a rule, even as simple as redefining a reserved constant. You'll get away with it more often that not, but you might be very sorry the day you won't. Besides, C compilation is very fast, including a couple more headers should make no noticeable difference.

Comment: @kuroineko Re: compare return values in pre C99 return 0 or 1: see [Any C compiler where “==” evaluates to larger than one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10632237/2410359).

Comment: Oh, good to know. I didn't realize even the K&R defined the return value of these operators. Anyway, I shied from the printf hair-splitting tedium. Pissing contests are not my thing, and who cares about the 1.000.000th variant of fizzbuzz anyway?

Comment: @kuroineko It's worth pointing out that K&R-style C is hardly modern though. The C standard changed a bit since '89 as well.

Comment: Seriously, give me a break. K&R style was already a thing of the past in the 90's. Knowing when the return value of == was first defined is just an amusing bit of lore, with zero practical value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
>  #define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
> ```

You are not permitted to define standard library names yourself.  So just include `<stdlib.h>`, or omit the `return` from `main()` (remember, C will provide a success return if you don't provide one).

> ```
> void fizzbuzz(int n) {
> ```

We could give that internal linkage:

```
static void fizzbuzz(int n) {
```

> ```
> char result[9] = "";  // strlen("fizzbuzz") + 1 == 9
> ```

Instead of manually calculating, we could use `sizeof "fizzbuzz"` to let the compiler do that for us.

> ```
>     if (!*result) sprintf(result, "%d", n);
> ```

We should be using `snprintf()` here, as the decimal representation of `n` can be longer than `result` has capacity for (even on common platforms with 32-bit `int`).

I would avoid writing to `result` in this case - we can format directly to `stdout`:

```
    if (*result) {
        puts(result);
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
```

`main` should be specific about its arguments:

```
 int main(void)
```

---

## Modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fizzbuzz(int n)
{
    char result[sizeof "fizzbuzz"] = "";
    if (n % 3 == 0) { strcat(result, "fizz"); }
    if (n % 5 == 0) { strcat(result, "buzz"); }
    if (*result) {
        puts(result);
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 1;  i <= 100;  ++i) {
        fizzbuzz(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there are a few things I am not sure I understand correctly. "You are not permitted to define standard library names yourself." Even with all the compiler options enabled, I don't get an error, not permitted by whom? And also is the implicit return only valid for certain compilers? I seem to remember that. Thank you again.

Comment: Not permitted by the C standard (it's undefined behaviour, IIRC).  Compilers are not obliged to detect that you do so, and you probably get away with it in most cases.  Default return from `main()` (and only from `main()`) is standard C, since C99 I think.  So all compliant compilers in 2021 should accept that.

Comment: Technically it isn't redefining since I did not import stdlib? Anyway I appreciate your answer, I accepted it.

Comment: I'll try and find a reference for that.  However, be aware that the standard library headers are allowed to include each other (e.g. `<stdio.h>` is allowed to transitively include `<stdlib.h>`) so you cannot say for definite what's not included.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that, it's a fair point. Thanks.

Comment: @Toby In C++, headers may include any additional header they want. C doesn't have (nor really need) that provision.

Comment: _"Even with all the compiler options enabled, I don't get an error, not permitted by whom?"_ - If that's your attitude, you're in for a world of pain with C ;) - There's _lots_ of things in C that won't trigger a compiler error (or even warning), but are still prohibited and lead to hard to debug problems. Most Undefined Behavior pitfalls fall in this category.

Comment: One good thing you've done "silently" is to put braces round every conditionally-executed section.  To the OP: This is considered good practise under every coding standard I'm aware of, because a common error is to start with a single-line conditionally-executed statement, then need to add a second line and forget to put both lines within braces.  The result if you do that is that the first line is conditionally executed (depending on the "if" statement or whatever), but the second line isn't covered by the condition and is always executed.

Comment: @Graham, where I work, we currently do not require those braces. However, we require code to have been formatted with clang-format, so this mitigates the problem that you describe. (And I actually remember falling into this trap when adding a debug output to see whether a branch was taken, only to achieve that now that conditional statement was always executed.)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you can include the appropriate header, do that. Redefining yourself is error-prone even where allowed. This is C not C++, headers are simple enough it doesn't significantly influence compile-time.
2. If you add the origin of a constant in a comment, try to instead let the compiler determine it from the true source for you.

   ```
    char result[9] = "";  // strlen("fizzbuzz") + 1 == 9
   ```

   becomes the simpler and shorter

   ```
    char result[sizeof "fizzbuzz"] = "";
   ```
3. If you can, avoid copying strings around. Your pattern has period 3*5==15, so use an array. You can even compress it if you want, though that is overkill.
4. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()` since C99. While `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` might be a *different* successful execution, afaik there is no implementation which differentiates.

[This is what it looks like when you pander to the little tin god, without completely loosing your head:](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8eca6a28ceade410)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fizzbuzz(unsigned n) {
#define Z "\n\0"
#define F "fizz"
#define X "%u" Z
    const char* text = X F Z F "buzz\n";
    static const char index[] = {
        sizeof(X F Z),   1,         1,         sizeof(X), 1,
        sizeof(X F Z F), sizeof(X), 1,         1,         sizeof(X),
        sizeof(X F Z F), 1,         sizeof(X), 1,         1,
    };
#undef X
#undef F
#undef Z
    printf(text + index[n % 15] - 1, n);
}

int main() {
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
        fizzbuzz(i);
}
```

Or after [encoding data and offsets with a custom program](//wandbox.org/permlink/7LcNL8QK06CPmzmQ) (we are now far beyond overkill), it [becomes this](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b43f66857cb401f):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fizzbuzz(unsigned n) {
    const char* p = "\31\17\17\23\17\35\23\17\17\23\35\17\23"
        "\17\17%u\n\0fizz\n\0fizzbuzz\n";
    printf(p + p[n % 15], n);
}

int main() {
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
        fizzbuzz(i);
}
```

The difficult part was converting the calculated string into a valid short source-code literal. Trickier than one might think.

Comment: I was worried that `printf("fizz\n", 3);` might be undefined behaviour, but [it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579752/1270789).

Comment: I am not familiar with the idiom "pander to the little tin god"; what does this mean?

Comment: Think of what can be accomplished with all that performance gain!

Comment: @CodyGray The little tin god means that in the end, it takes far more prominence than deserved. And in this case, it is obviously the little tin god of efficiency.

Comment: @t_d_milan That was obviously never the point.

Answer (score 1):

**Re-use**

> could include stdlib so as not to have to define EXIT_SUCCESS myself, but as I only needed this constant, it's a little clearer and more efficient to do this

Consider someone uses your good code as part of a larger task and does include `<stdlib.h>`, then the compiler may warn about the redefinition.  Now the next coder needs to spend time sorting this out.

Tip: plan for code re-use and consider the next guy.  Avoid re-implementing the standard library.

---

**Buffer too small**

`char result[9] .... sprintf(result, "%d", n)` --> `result` too small for all `int`.  Be more generous.

Various ways to pre-calculate buffer needs.

```
 #define INT_STRING_N (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
 #define FIZZBUZZ_STRING_N 9
 #define BUFF_N (INT_STRING_N > FIZZBUZZ_STRING_N ? INT_STRING_N : FIZZBUZZ_STRING_N)

 char result[BUFF_N];
```

I favor using 2x buffers (twice the expected max needed size) and `snprintf()` for less controlled cases.